# How can I get the cookies from a subdomain?

Tags: javascript, html, subdomain

Let's assume I'm on `sub.example.org`, how can I get the cookies of `.example.org` from there? If that's not possible, is there a workaround like an hack or whatever that redirects to `.example.org` and then stores the cookies?

Comment: @SamOnela that doesn't completely answer my questions. I'm asking also for a workaround of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cookie was set as `HttpOnly` flag, and the browser made me not able to get the cookie for JavaScript.

Comment: That has nothing to do with being in a subdomain. Javascript from the main domain shouldn't be able to access it, either.

Comment: As much as I agree with @Barmar's comment, `HttpOnly` is pretty much the only thing that can prevent reading the cookie in OP's situation (except if you have 2 identical cookies set in both domains, like in Barmar's answer).

Comment: @DidierL I wasn't contradicting that, just pointing out that the restriction is not specific to subdomains.

Comment: This is an answer to a different question -- the question never says that this flag is set.

Answer (score 11):

A web page only has visibility to the cookie with the most specific domain that matches its URL.

So if both `example.org` and `sub.example.org` both have a cookie named `mycookie`, a web page in `sub.example.org` can only access the one in the subdomain. It hides the cookie in the `example.org` domain, and there's no way to access it.

But if there's only a cookie in `example.org`, it will be visible to both `example.org` and `sub.example.org` pages.

When creating a cookie, it defaults to the full domain of the page, but the code can specify a less specific domain. So if `sub.example.org` creates a cookie, it will default to `domain=sub.example.org`. But the code can override this by putting `domain=.example.org` in the cookie explicitly.

More details can be found in [The Definitive Guide to Cookie Domains](http://erik.io/blog/2014/03/04/definitive-guide-to-cookie-domains/).

Comment: The cookie is in `.example.org`, how can I access it from `sub.example.org`? In Javascript.

Comment: You don't need to do anything special if there's no more specific cookie shadowing it. It's visible automatically.

Comment: `alert(document.cookie)` doesn't show the cookie I want.

Comment: Does it show another cookie with the same name in the subdomain?

Comment: Take a look at the link I added to the answer.

Comment: what do you mean with cookie with the same name?

Comment: @WayneXMayersX Every cookie has a name. If both `example.org` and `sub.example.org` create cookies with the same name, `sub.example.org` will only be able to access the one in `sub.example.org`. But it should still be able to access other cookies inherited from `example.org`.