# Why can't I set session cookies? [Sovled]

Tags: javascript, session-cookies, roblox

I set session cookies but it creates new cookies. I'm tired of this Do you know how to fix it?
Code:

```js
document.cookie = ".ROBLOSECURITY=cookie; expires=session; path=/";
```

Comment: What's the difference between setting a cookie and creating a cookie? Please elaborate

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/qGVHV4Y likes this @smac89

Comment: I'm no cookie expert, but it looks like the domain where you are setting the cookie is not the same. One is at `www.roblox.com` while the other is at `robolox.com`. From what I've read, you can only set cookies on the most specific domain you are on

Comment: Perhaps you can try specifying the domain. So something like `document.cookie = ".ROBLOSECURITY=cookie; expires=session; path=/; domain=.roblox.com"`

Comment: See if anything said here helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45700816/how-can-i-get-the-cookies-from-a-subdomain

Answer (score 1):

Let's check [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#write_a_new_cookie)

> ;domain=domain (e.g., 'example.com' or 'subdomain.example.com'). If
> not specified, this defaults to the host portion of the current
> document location. Contrary to earlier specifications, leading dots in
> domain names are ignored, but browsers may decline to set the cookie
> containing such dots. If a domain is specified, subdomains are always
> included.

> Note: The domain must match the domain of the JavaScript
> origin. Setting cookies to foreign domains will be silently ignored.

Your first cookie with domain `www.roblox.com` will be accessible only at `www.roblox.com/...` page but `.roblox.com`'s cookie may be accessed by JS from all `roblox.com` subdomains.

Here is a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39708227/13946204)

So as @smac89 wrote in comment, You should add domain when create new cookie

```
document.cookie = ".ROBLOSECURITY=cookie; expires=session; path=/; domain=.roblox.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax for what you want.

You can either not set the expiration value, the cookie will expire at the end of the session, or choose an arbitrarily large value.

Be aware that some browsers have problems with dates past 2038 (when the Unix epoch time exceeds a 32-bit integer).

See : https://stackoverflow.com/a/532660/1901857